# Is this proof of multivariable limits legit $\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 - y^2}{x^2 + y^2}$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Show that the limit  $\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 - y^2}{x^2 + y^2}$ does not exists.

Step 1) let $x=0$ $\Rightarrow \frac{-y^2}{y^2} =1$
Step 2) let $x = y \Rightarrow \frac{0}{2y^2} =0 $

the two limits are not the same so the limit does not exists.

Is this legit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{-y^2}{y^2} = -1\neq 1.$$ Other than that, your proof is correct.

Comment: yeah i forgot the minus sign. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct. you chose different paths and the answers were different.